# Is referential transparency/functional purity a best practice or does it depend on preference?

Tags: functional-programming, referential-transparency

I would like to know if there is consensus as to whether or not functional purity is considered a best practice or if it depends on preference or programming style. In other words is this up for debate, or is this effectively determined? All the information I've been able to find suggests that it is a virtue with no disadvantages. Is this true?

I would like to compile a list of best practices for our local community of practice, and I would like to know the degree to which this should be included.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @MarcB Why is this a bad question? I read the dont-ask rules; however, this seems to be deterministic (not an open-ended or subjective question). Is there consensus or not?

Comment: @MarkB So, no explanation as to why this was closed? Because the question doesn't obviously violate any of the rules in your link...

Comment: `there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”`

Comment: @MarcB, My question doesn't lack a problem, in contrast to the cited example from the rules. I'm not drumming up idle conversation; I'm asking whether or not there is authoritative research, literature, etc on a specific matter for a specific purpose. The answer to this deterministic question is the solution to the implicit problem, like many, many other rightly open questions in SO. However, I elaborated the specifics of my problem, even though they contribute nothing toward finding an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Mutation and other side effects are best avoided in the same way goto is best avoided. That is to say, there are cases where it is useful, but more often then not it can be eliminated and replaced by more structured solutions without too much difficulty.

Of course, a lot of that depends on the language and libraries you are using. Side-effect-free programming is *very* inconvenient in languages not designed for it (i.e., almost all mainstream languages).

Independent of specific language constraints, there can also be cases of mutable data structures or imperative algorithms that are difficult to substitute by functional ones without changing the big-O complexity class. In most relevant cases, good solutions are known these days, but sometimes they are tricky, and in some cases, active research.

That all said, you can well have side effects without losing purity. See e.g. Haskell's use of monads.

Comment: I appreciate the detail in your answer--would it be safe to summarize your answer as "There isn't concensus about whether functional purity is a virtue in all cases"? Would you say functional purity is even a good rule of thumb in most cases for the most common languages (namely those languages not designed to be functional)? I'm trying to pigeon-hole your answer to fit the context of my question.

Comment: Ultimately, code should be clean and simple. If impure solutions are significantly simpler in the language at hand, then they are preferable. So pragmatically, purity isn't a virtue unconditionally and without considering the context.

Comment: Thank you. Personally, I found that comment to be a valuable summary of your official answer. Consider editing it into your answer? At any rate, I +1'd your answer and accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You should reduce unintentional complexity in your code, as a general rule. This is uncontroversial.

One of the best ways to reduce complexity is to limit the information channels in your code -- the ways in which information can "leak" from one component to another. This keeps your code simpler and more modular, easier to test, easier to use, and easier to maintain.

Mutable variables and other side effects are by definition information channels, and ones that are relatively "hidden" compared to the usual channel of function argument and result. Code with them is like a sieve, with information leaking in and out of the code, in transient, temporally-dependent ways, through the mutable variables.

Globally visible mutable variables are the worst, as they (potentially) leak information across your entire code base, adding many tangled information channels to manage. Locally scoped mutable variables only leak temporal information for a few lines at most. You should avoid the former, and be careful with the latter.

So, in the goal of minimizing complexity and increasing modularity, you should avoid leaky side effects, as they pollute your code with unnecessary complexity. Eschewing mutable variables and other side effects is an excellent rule of thumb to follow.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and I'm inclined to agree; however, is there any controversy surrounding your conclusion? Do you know of any current authoritative discussion you could link to? Or any literature suggesting that your rule-of-thumb conclusion is supported by authorities in the professional community? Basically, I would like to know to what extent this is up for debate, because I would like to make it a company guideline, and I would like to know the degree to which this is supported by authorities on the matter?